# Jsoup выбивает ошибку при попытке соединения

Tags: java, android-studio, jsoup

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("https://hackinformer.com/category/tutorial-guides/").get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
}
```

Пытаюсь сконектиться с любым сайтом, но выдаёт ошибки:

```
04-14 21:37:03.942 29580-29580/com.twikoffin.hackinformer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.twikoffin.hackinformer, PID: 29580
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.twikoffin.hackinformer/com.twikoffin.hackinformer.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2684)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1496)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6186)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
     Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1303)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:86)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:74)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:752)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:187)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:156)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:98)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:346)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:329)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:247)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:457)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:126)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:730)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:706)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:299)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:288)
        at com.twikoffin.hackinformer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6684)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2637)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1496) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6186) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
04-14 21:37:03.950 29580-29580/com.twikoffin.hackinformer I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 29580 SIG: 9
```

И приложение естественно вылетает. Помогите пожалуйста, заранее спасибо.

Comment: @zRrr И что мне с этим делать?

Answer (score 2):

Ответ прямо в стэктрэйсе - `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Происходит это из-за попытки работы с сетью в UI потоке. Для сетевых запросов используйте [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) или просто выполняйте свой запрос в отдельном потоке:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      Document doc = null;
      try {
         doc = Jsoup.connect("https://hackinformer.com/category/tutorial-guides/").get();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
      }                 
   }
}).run();
```